# Order by in two different related tables on eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

guys

I having struggles trying to pass an orderBy argument to relational tables.

This is my case: I want to order the result by some columns on books table (this is working just fine) and also on some more books_offers but I'm getting `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`  error with any books_offers column.

http://localhost:8000/offers // fine

http://localhost:8000/offers?oderBy=category:asc // fine

http://localhost:8000/offers?oderBy=countries:asc // error

```
   class OffersController extends Controller
    {
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $limit = $request->input('limit', 30);
            $offset = $request->input('offset', 0);
            $orderByInput = $request->input('orderBy');
            $orderByParams = !empty($orderByInput) ? explode(':', $orderByInput): ['id', 'DESC'];

            $offersQuery = Books::where('is_direct', '=', 1)
                ->with('offers')
                ->whereHas('offers', function ($query) {
                    $query->enable()
                    ->select(['id', 'offer_id', 'name', 'devices', 'countries', 'payment_type']); // I want to order by using this columns too
                })
                ->limit($limit)
                ->offset($offset)
                ->orderBy($orderByParams[0], $orderByParams[1]); //this works just fine with id, name and category
                $result = $offersQuery->get(['id', 'name', 'category', 'description']);

        return response()->json($OffersQuery, 200);
    }
```

Can you please give me some advices?

Comment: you have to use join for this scenerio

Comment: A book can have many offers, right? Which offer should be used for sorting the book?

Comment: Yes @JonasStaudenmeir , a book can have many offers. I should order the result by devices, offer_id, payment_type, and countries.

Comment: If a book has three offers with different `countries` value, which one should the query use to sort the book?

Comment: Hi @JonasStaudenmeir doesn't matter, should order all the offers by countries values asc or dsc.

Answer (score 0):

Is the countries field in the books or book_offers table? I'm thinking its in the book_offers, thus the eager loading needs to be constrained per https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

with your particular setup (ordering by a property on the model or one of its eager loaded relationship models) Im not sure this can be done.

Heres how you might constrain the eager load

```
class OffersController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $limit = $request->input('limit', 30);
        $offset = $request->input('offset', 0);
        $orderByInput = $request->input('orderBy');
        $orderByParams = !empty($orderByInput) ? explode(':', $orderByInput): ['id', 'DESC'];

        $offersQuery = Books::where('is_direct', '=', 1)
            ->with('offers')
            ->whereHas('offers', function ($query) {
                $query->enable()
                ->select(['id', 'offer_id', 'name', 'devices', 'countries', 'payment_type']); // I want to order by using this columns too
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
            })
            ->limit($limit)
            ->offset($offset);
            $result = $offersQuery->get(['id', 'name', 'category', 'description']);

    return response()->json($OffersQuery, 200);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks @ben-sholdice but how can I orderBy the fields on books table? It's both tables that I need to orderby.